# CentOS 7 sshd_config error

Tags: ssh, centos7

Because my ip address will not change often, I want only my ip address can access SSH of my gen4 CentOS7 VPS server.

This is the config file content(with commented out lines removed) of file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin no
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
Match Address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  #here is  my real ip address 
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

After running

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

, I got following error:

Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sshd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

After running:

```
systemctl status sshd.service
```

The result is as follows:

```
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-08-21 21:34:52 MST; 40s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 15994 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 15994 (code=exited, status=255)
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check the logs for an error message.

Comment: Also, `/usr/sbin/sshd -T`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T
```

I got error message as follows:

```
Directive 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication' is not allowed within a Match block
```

So I moved my Match block to last part of the file, it solved my problem.

Thank you all for the instructions.